# My Python trapezoidal code is saying x not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the integration of `Sin^2(x)/x^2` using trapezoidal rule but while running it is saying `x` id not defined. Can anyone suggest me what is wrong?

```
import math
c=math.sin`

def trapezoidal(f,  a, b, N):
    if x!=0:
        h=(b-a)/N
        s=0.0
        s+=f(a)/2.0
        for i in range (1,N):
            s+=f(a+i*h)
        s+=f(b)/2.0
        Y=s*h
    else:
        y=1
    return Y`
for n in range (1,11):
    N=2**n
    result=trapezoidal(lambda x:((c(x)*c(x))/(x**2)), 0, 1000, N)
    print(repr(n).rjust(10), repr(result).rjust(30))`
```

Comment: You're not calling x in the function.
This is why you have the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the x in the function. In your case you want to loop over every element in the function f.

If you don't want to use the pythonic way, you can have a look at numpy and scipy. These packages offer optimised functions for basic operation such as integrations and matrix calculations. Have a look at np.trapz (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html), sp.integrate (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html)

Comment: but i  am calling the function x at the end. lambda x: (c(x)*c(x)/X**2).Can u please be more specific and tellme what i should modify.

Comment: as I said, create a loop over the function. This will be your x.

Comment: i have done it in other way and it worked  also but i wantedto do it in this way only. for simple functions like integraton of x or x^2 it is working bur for the above function it is not.

Comment: Do you mean that i should create a for loop over the function at start instead of doint it at the end.